# JSONp Datetime Javascript query fails on data.sparkfun iot

Tags: javascript, json

been trying to select data from data.sparkfun based on when its posted. I want to display weather data from the currenttime and a day back.
The stream is at: [LINK](https://data.sparkfun.com/streams/yA0EjKV3owhKNx1NlN3w)
I am no coder, just hacking my way through here.

One json line is like this:

```
[{
  "humidity": "37.8919",
  "hectopascals": "1017.7725",
  "rainin": "0.0000",
  "tempc": "21.3162",
  "winddir": "-1",
  "windspeedkmh": "0.0000",
  "windgustkmh_10m": "0.0000",
  "timestamp": "2017-02-25T15:11:08.581Z"
}]
```

The code I use is at: https://www.hanscees.com/photon/charts-data-sparkfun.html

```
function drawChart2() {

  var public_key = 'yA0EjKV3owhKNx1NlN3w';

  // JSONP request
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: 'https://data.sparkfun.com/output/' + public_key + '.json',
    //data: {page: 1},  see http://phant.io/docs/output/http/
    // https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=40621
    data: {
      'gt': {
        'timestamp': 'now - 2d'
      }
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
  }).done(function(results) {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
    data.addColumn('number', 'TempC');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Humidity');

    $.each(results, function(i, row) {
      data.addRow([
        (new Date(row.timestamp)),
        parseFloat(row.tempc),
        parseFloat(row.humidity)
      ]);
    }); // each row
    // see https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#dual-y-charts

    var materialOptions = {
      chart: {
        title: 'TempC, Humidity outside'
      },
      width: 550,
      height: 500,
      series: {
        // Gives each series an axis name that matches the Y-axis below.
        0: {
          axis: 'TempC'
        },
        1: {
          axis: 'Humid'
        }
      },
      axes: {
        // Adds labels to each axis; they don't have to match the axis names.
        y: {
          Pressure: {
            label: 'TempC (Celsius)'
          },
          Humid: {
            label: 'Humidity'
          }
        }
      }
    };

    var materialChart = new google.charts.Line(ChartDivTemp);
    materialChart.draw(data, materialOptions);

  }); // results

} // jsondata
```

but the diagrams are either displaying all data in the json file (which makes it extremely slow), or when I use:

```
data: {page: 1},
```

it shows about 4 hours of data.
How can help to format the query correctly? This line:

```
data: {
  'gt': {
    'timestamp': 'now - 2d'
  }
}
```

Comment: So you need the data from the previous two days ?

Comment: yes, from the previous two days

Answer (score 0):

I did a post request thru **Postman** and it worked:
https://data.sparkfun.com/output/yA0EjKV3owhKNx1NlN3w.json?lt[timestamp]=now%20-2day

```
data: {
  'lt': {
    'timestamp': 'now - 2day'
  }
}
```

So you code should work by adding **2day** and changing **gt to lt**

Comment: wonderfull! Thank you!! But it is GT, not LT. My mistake was apparently I used dayS  instaed of day, and 'lt'[space]:

Comment: have a look now at https://www.hanscees.com/photon/charts-data-sparkfun.html, it works

Answer (score 0):

This code does what I wanted:

```
// JSONP request
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: 'https://data.sparkfun.com/output/' + public_key + '.json',
      //data: {page: 1},  see http://phant.io/docs/output/http/
    // https://forum.sparkfun.com/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=40621
  data: {'gt': {'timestamp': 'now - 2day'}},
      dataType: 'jsonp',
    }).done(function (results) {
```

[image]